No way to terminate python process; using trio, running as root, reading /proc/bus/input/devices
I wanted to achieve some of the functionality that keyboard python package offers, but without threads, instead using trio.
I created an async function that reads /proc/bus/input/devices to look for keyboards, then starts a task (in a nursery) for each keyboard found - basically it opens the keyboard /dev/input/event/... file (binary read mode) and reads chunks of bytes, parses using struct module and so on. Everything works nice, I get a stream of lines like I wanted: "a" pressed, "a" released, etc.
Now the weird part, I can't terminate that script. If I press Ctrl+C, or send kill -INT, it stops reporting which keys were pressed/released, but python (the process) does not stop. I have to kill it with SIGTERM. I also wrote an if to run sys.exit(0) when the key being released is q - no difference. Same with cancelling trio nursery.cancel_scope.
Can I force python to print a traceback when it's in that weird state? Or is there any other way to debug where exactly it is frozen?

The most common cause for this problem is swallowing Cancelled exceptions.
You need to make sure that every except BaseException and every bare except: (which you really should avoid) results in a re-raise of the original exception.
Also, async code in finally: clauses are iffy because the cancellation doesn't go away; you should wrap any async code in them with with fail_after(2, shield=True): or some other reasonable short timeout.
If that doesn't help, Trio has an instrumentation framework you can hook into to watch which subtask causes the problem. You can trigger a traceback by running your code with pdb but they are unlikely to be helpful when the Trio mainloop is just sitting there, outside of any tasks.
Finally you might try using strace, in case the problem is a blocking non-async call that you forgot to not use.

checked: not a single try block, not using trio cancellation (when I tried to exit with sys.exit(0)). Just a bunch of async context managers to read from files, nursery and memory channel. For now I exit the script with os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM), and read about strace in the meantime

You're using trio cancellation because when an unwinding exception hits a nursery, then the nursery has to cancel everything running inside it before the exception can continue unwinding. Both SIGINT and sys.exit work by raising an exception, so if your program isn't responsive to cancellation, their exceptions will get "stuck" and won't be able to unwind and exit your program.
